# Bootstrap Timeline with images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

After I copied and pasted the code from https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/timeline/#images, **why are the images looking big** and what do I have to do to make the content for the left and right side smaller and have the line coming down the middle? Run the execution and you'll see what I'm talking about. This is also happening when I execute it from my text editor too.

```html
<!-- Timeline CSS -->
<link href="css/addons-pro/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Timeline CSS - minified-->
<link href="css/addons-pro/timeline.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Timeline -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="timeline-main">
      <!-- Timeline Wrapper -->
      <ul class="stepper stepper-vertical timeline timeline-simple timeline-images pl-0">

        <li>
          <!--Section Title -->
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="circle cyan lighten-1">1</span>
          </a>

          <!-- Section Description -->
          <div class="step-content ml-3 p-0 hoverable">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(135).jpg" class="img-fluid"
              alt="Responsive image">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold p-4 mb-0">Ut enim ad minim veniam</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-4 mb-0"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2017</p>
            <p class="mb-0 p-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
              incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
              ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <!--Section Title -->
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="circle cyan lighten-1">2</span>
          </a>

          <!-- Section Description -->
          <div class="step-content mr-xl-3 p-0 hoverable">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(129).jpg" class="img-fluid"
              alt="Responsive image">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold p-4 mb-0">Duis aute irure dolor</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-4 mb-0"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2016</p>
            <p class="mb-0 p-4">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
              architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
              aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
              sequi nesciunt.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!--Section Title -->
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="circle cyan lighten-1">3</span>
          </a>

          <!-- Section Description -->
          <div class="step-content ml-3 p-0 hoverable">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(131).jpg" class="img-fluid"
              alt="Responsive image">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold p-4 mb-0">Sed ut nihil unde omnis</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-4 mb-0"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2015</p>
            <p class="mb-0 p-4">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
              adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
              aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
              suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure
              reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
              dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <!--Section Title -->
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="circle cyan lighten-1">4</span>
          </a>

          <!-- Section Description -->
          <div class="step-content mr-xl-3 p-0 hoverable">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(125).jpg" class="img-fluid"
              alt="Responsive image">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold p-4 mb-0"> Quis autem vel eum voluptate</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-4 mb-0"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2014</p>
            <p class="mb-0 p-4">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
              praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint
              occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi,
              id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!--Section Title -->
          <a href="#!">
            <span class="circle cyan lighten-1">5</span>
          </a>

          <!-- Section Description -->
          <div class="step-content ml-3 p-0 hoverable">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(144).jpg" class="img-fluid"
              alt="Responsive image">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold p-4 mb-0">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-4 mb-0"><i class="far fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2013</p>
            <p class="mb-0 p-4">Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus
              saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum
              hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut
              perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Timeline Wrapper -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Timeline -->
```

Comment: You're asking help for a paid addon. Which means in order to help you, one would have to buy the addon first. Your question is therefore ***off-topic*** on [SO]. You must ask for help from MDB support team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking help with proprietary (non open-source) software.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the existence of the css files

```
<!-- Timeline CSS -->
<link href="css/addons-pro/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Timeline CSS - minified-->
<link href="css/addons-pro/timeline.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and the original code together and the original code is working correctly
There is a problem navigating the timeline style files

check directory or give us some details about folder and file directory